# Filter relevant geojson data based on a selected datapoint

Tags: geospatial, tableau

I'll outline the situation and challenge I have a bit more clearly. I have multiple different datasets:

- A set of locations where products are sold (name, long, lat)
- A geojson dataset with geometry (polygon data per postal code area) for each postal code area in the country
- A one-hot encoded dataset with postal code area per location name where they sell their products (a column for each postal code area, with a 1 if they sell in that area, and a 0 if not)

In the sheet below I'm trying to do the following:

Select one of the locations (orange dots) and only show the polygons (geojson data) that that specific location services (from the one-hot encoded list).

[image: Map with sales locations]

The only way I've been able to make this work is to create a calculated field for each of the locations by hand (which isn't what I want, there's way too many locations for that).

What approach could I take to find a solution here?